# PostgreSQL How to retrieve data from certain month and day "11-29" to a month and day "12-10"

Tags: postgresql

I have a date column "birthday"

and I want to retrieve the users who meet the required date range like '11-29' to '12-10' and whatever the year.

What I have so far is

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd') >= '11-29' 
   AND TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd') < '12-10'
```

Problem is when I query this, I get users who's birthday is 1999-12-20

=== UPDATED ===
I'm sorry I gave wrong date comparison example

The correct date is below

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd') >= '12-30' 
   AND TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd') < '01-10'
```

and a user whose birthday is '01-02' doesn't come out

Comment: You are ignoring the year? what if its a leap year?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ yes I ignore the year, and It doesn't matter if it is a leap year because I query this using python's datetime package to get date

Comment: What is your eaxct code? All of your strings are double-quoted, but this is not allowed in (Postgre)SQL. I feel like there is happening something else.. (since ```select '12-20' < '12-10';``` yields ```false``` on my local machine)

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I just updated the query with a single quote

Comment: The query looks correct. Try to reproduce the error in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11) and deliver the link.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Sorry I gave wrong example. I just updated question. Thanks

Comment: The updated query makes no sense as the condition is always false.

Comment: @klin That's right! the condition is always false. I know that but I don't know how to compare date between years

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. If you really have table named like that you have to use double quotes `"user"`

Comment: It's simple - if the dates are from different years then replace `AND` with `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a tuple comparison here:

```
select *
from "user"
where ( extract(month from birthday), extract(day from birthday) ) between (10,1) and (12,30)
```

This would however not work if you want to get the birthdays between e.g. November and March (because this crosses over to the next year). You could e.g. write two conditions then (one for November to December and one for January to March)

Comment: Thanks Now I got an idea how to solve this problem! get two conditions!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `doy` (Day of Year) and do the math (I chose a known leap year for simplicity):

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE extract(doy from ('2012-' || TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd'))::date) >= extract(doy from '2012-11-29'::date) 
   AND extract(doy from ('2012-' || TO_CHAR(user.birthday, 'mm-dd'))::date) < extract(doy from '2012-12-10'::date);
```

Output:

```
edb=# create table mytable (id int, birthday date);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into mytable values (1, '2019-11-30');
INSERT 0 1
edb=# insert into mytable values (2,'2019-12-20');
INSERT 0 1
edb=# SELECT *                                    
FROM mytable
WHERE extract(doy from ('2012-' || TO_CHAR(birthday, 'mm-dd'))::date) >= extract(doy from '2012-11-29'::date) 
   AND extract(doy from ('2012-' || TO_CHAR(birthday, 'mm-dd'))::date) < extract(doy from '2012-12-10'::date);
;
 id |      birthday       
----+---------------------
  1 | 2019-11-30 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Note that `doy` also accounts for Leap Year:

```
edb=# select extract(doy from '2010-11-29'::date);
 date_part 
-----------
       333
(1 row)

edb=# select extract(doy from '2011-11-29'::date);
 date_part 
-----------
       333
(1 row)
edb=# select extract(doy from '2012-11-29'::date);
 date_part 
-----------
       334
(1 row)
```

Therefore, if you are looking to calculate across years, then you will need to do a little bit more string manipulation